# How can I determine the primary, secondary or tertiary color of a hex code?

Tags: python, colors

I want to write some code which can take a hex color and accurately guess its primary, secondary or tertiary color.

For example, if I input `#0000FF`, or `#002FA7`, or `#004950` it would return `blue`. (I don't want it to return things like `AquaBlue` or `Cobolt` or `Navy`, but rather the simple color `blue`).

Comment: Are those RGB values?

Comment: I think you have to check the limits of values and classify into 3 groups.

Comment: Would `blue` be the primary, secondary, or tertiary color of these codes? Why? What would the result of `#000000`, `#666666`, `#FFFFFF` be?

Comment: @wwii I can convert between hex and hsv (or whatever) if it helps make it easier.

Comment: @RahulKP yes I think the solution is something like that. I'm surprised I can't find a library for this though.

Comment: @LutzHorn I would hope that would be something like black, black, white.

Comment: Why would  `#666666` be black, not, for example, grey? What us the set of possible return values?

Comment: @LutzHorn Sure I can accept it as grey. There just needs to be a defined boundary between each color, so w and x are grey, y and z are black, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple python function to classify that. The colors like black and white (`#000000` and `#FFFFFF`) you have to modify the function according to your requirements. Because it's hold the same values for `rgb`.

The function convert `hex` to `rgb` values and take the maximum value and classify according to that.

```
def hex_to_rgb(value):
        value = value.lstrip('#')
        lv = len(value)
        colors = tuple(int(value[i:i + lv // 3], 16) for i in range(0, lv, lv // 3))
        pri_colrs = ['Red','Green','Blue']
        return pri_colrs[colors.index(max(colors))]
```

**Results**

```
In [33]: hex_to_rgb('#002FA7')
Out[33]: 'Blue'
In [34]: hex_to_rgb('#0000FF')
Out[34]: 'Blue'
In [35]: hex_to_rgb('#004950')
Out[35]: 'Blue'
```

Comment: `hex_to_rgb("#000000")` and `hex_to_rgb("#ffffff")` returning `Red`  looks strange to me. Why is the result for `hex_to_rgb("#00ffff")` `Green`?

Comment: @LutzHorn Because it's carry same values for `rgb`. So `max` will return first index that's why it's `red`.  That's why i mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start -

Say the string `c = '#004950'` is a hex RGB color.

Define some slices to separate the rgb values

```
>>> red = slice(1,3)
>>> blue = slice(3,5)
>>> green = slice(5, 7)
```

You need to find the magnitudes - I'll use a function and map it to the rgb values

```
>>> def f(s):
    return int(n, base = 16)
>>> rgb = map(f, (c[red], c[green], c[blue]))
```

Now we need to know which has the highest magnitude:

```
>>> # a couple more helpers
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> color = itemgetter(0)
>>> value = itemgetter(1)
>>> 
>>> colors = zip(['red', 'green', 'blue'], rgb)
>>> colors = sorted(colors, key = value)
>>> tertiary, secondary, primary = map(color, colors)
>>> primary, secondary, tertiary
('blue', 'green', 'red')
>>>
```